# A bit of confusion with the Gaussian measure and pushforward by a random vector

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, gaussian-integral

Let $d\mu$ be a centered Gaussian measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the covariance matrix $\sigma$ and $X : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be any measurable mapping. Or we can simply regard $X$ as a random vector.

Now, define the pushforward $d[X_* \mu]$ of $\mu$ by $X$ as
\begin{equation}
[X_* \mu](E):=\mu(X^{-1}(E))
\end{equation}
for any Borel set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Also, write $X=(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ where each $X_i : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable for $i=1,\cdots,n$.

Then, is it true that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} X_i(x) X_j(x) \text{ }d[X_* \mu](x)= \sigma_{ij}
\end{equation}
for $i,j=1,\cdots,n$, where $\sigma_{ij}$ is the $(ij)$-entry of the covariance matrix $\sigma$.

I think this formula is a bit of a tautology but cannot verify it rigorously..

Could anyone help me?

Comment: @geetha290krm No, then you should remove $X_*$. $d\mu$ is the Gaussian measure and $X$ is "any" random vector.